# Angular 15 dynamic variable issue

Tags: angular

`In my angular 15` application, I am having below variable which is dynamic.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type on this line  this['customeFileName' + id]
```

const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;

```
 if (fileList.length > 0) { 

            let fileExt = '';
            const allowedExtensions = ["svg"];
            this.isDefault = false;
}
            
            this['customeFileName'  as any+ id]  = fileList[0];
```

What I tried is:

```
this['customeFileName'  as any+ id as any]  = fileList[0];
```

But this does not seems to be working, any one had similiar issue on `angular 15`.

Comment: why are you directly assigning to keys to `this` instead of defining `fileObj: {[property: string]: any} = {} ` and then `this.fileObj['customeFileName' + id] = fileList[0]`

Comment: I was wondering why question is downgraded.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to create a variable that will hold the data by ID. This variable can then be available on the component or service as needed:

```
type ID = number; // I assume

class MyService {
  customeFileName: Record<ID, File> = {};

  getFile(id: ID)?: File {
    return this.customeFileName[id];
  }

  saveData(fileList: FileList) {
    this.customeFileName[id] = fileList[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel the need to bind it to your component ? And why do you use such syntax ?

Keep it simple.

```js
private filesMap = new Map<string, File>();

// ...

this.filesMap.set(id, fileList[0]);
```

Comment: this is also good answer